# SQL-Server: Continue Last Value other then NULL, Incorrect Partition By

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I want to show the Last `EmployeeId` in column `Last_EmployeeId` for each `RoomNumber`. So when there's a `NULL` value, I should return the `EmployeeId` instead of `NULL`. The query below almost does the trick by `Partition by value_partition`, because the `value_partition` shows a different number for the not-NULL records. However, at a certain point the `value_partition` shows the exact same number for both NULL and not-NULL records (after ~3000 records). As a consequence it returns the `EmployeeId` also for all the unrelated rooms (as you can see in the pasted data snippet down below).

I use the following code:

```
;WITH Rooms_Rank AS ( 
SELECT 
    Rooms.*
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rooms.RoomNumber ORDER BY Rooms.[Date]) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rooms.RoomNumber, Rooms.beginDate ORDER BY Rooms.[Date]) AS Rnk--[Services].beginDate ORDER BY RoomDate.[Date]) AS Rnk
FROM Rooms
)
SELECT
  [Date]
  ,RoomNumber
  ,EmployeeId
  ,value_partition
  ,first_value(EmployeeId) OVER (PARTITION BY value_partition ORDER BY [Date]) AS Last_EmployeeId
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EmployeeId is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY RoomNumber, CAST([Date] AS DATE)) AS value_partition
    FROM Rooms_Rank
  ) AS q
ORDER BY [Date] ASC, RoomNumber
```

Small sample of the dataset (because this problem only arises after records 3000+)

| Date | RoomNumber | EmployeeId | value_partition | Last_EmployeeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-12 | 33 | 607 | 133 | 607 |
| 2020-10-12 | 34 | NULL | 136 | NULL |
| 2020-10-12 | 401 | NULL | 136 | NULL |
| 2020-10-12 | 71 | NULL | 223 | NULL |
| 2020-10-13 | 33 | 607 | 134 | 607 |
| 2020-10-13 | 34 | NULL | 136 | NULL |
| 2020-10-13 | 401 | NULL | 136 | NULL |
| 2020-10-13 | 71 | NULL | 223 | NULL |
| 2020-10-14 | 33 | 607 | 135 | 607 |
| 2020-10-14 | 34 | NULL | 136 | NULL |
| 2020-10-14 | 401 | NULL | 136 | NULL |
| 2020-10-14 | 71 | NULL | 223 | NULL |
| 2020-10-15 | 33 | 607 | 136 | 607 |
| 2020-10-15 | 34 | NULL | 136 | 607 |
| 2020-10-15 | 401 | NULL | 136 | 607 |
| 2020-10-15 | 71 | NULL | 223 | NULL |
| 2020-10-16 | 33 | NULL | 136 | 607 |
| 2020-10-16 | 34 | NULL | 136 | 607 |
| 2020-10-16 | 401 | NULL | 136 | 607 |
| 2020-10-16 | 71 | NULL | 223 | NULL |

As you can see 607 continues to show now for not only `RoomNumber` 33, but also 34 and 401.
How can I find a way to show the last 'EmployeeId' correctly?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the last non-`null` `employeeid` on a per-room basis. That would have been straigh-forward if SQL Server supported option `ignore nulls` to window function `lag()` - alas, very few databases do, and SQL Server is not one of them.

Instead, we can address this as a gaps-and-islands problem.We can put records into groups using a cumulative count of non-null values, then pick the only non-null value per group:

```
select t.*, 
    max(employeeid) over(partition by roomnumber, grp order by date) as lastemployeeid
from (
    select rr.*,
        count(employeeid) over(partition by roomnumber order by date) grp
    from rooms_rank rr
) rr
```